# place value into element

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.btn').click(function(){
        alert($(this).val());   
    });
});
</script>
<style>
.btn{width:20px; height:20px; background:red;}
</style>

<div class="btn" value="a"></div>
<div class="btn" value="b"></div>
<div class="btn" value="c"></div>
```

I have many div button use loop create from db.

im tring to detect the value of each button. so when user click, i can get the value from button.

My question is, is any way to set up the value into elements? or is any other options?

*If i use input type hidden, its not visible, if i use input type button, the value of text will display.*

Comment: A `div` doesn't have a value, that's invalid HTML

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Div elements can't have values. Those are for form controls.

If you want to store arbitrary data in an attribute then use a `data-` attribute.

```
<div class="btn" data-letter="a"></div>
```

and

```
alert($(this).data('letter'));
```

---

That said, if you want a button, then use a `<button>`. Browsers know that they are interactive elements. They tell users that they are interactive elements. People can focus them. Screen readers will announce them. You can give their functionality a server side fallback.

```
<button value="a">What does this button do?</button>
```

Then you can use `.val()`, since buttons are form controls.

Comment: whats different between data-value & data-letter?

Comment: There is a `value` attribute in HTML so avoiding reusing the word reduces opportunities for confusion, `letter` is fairly arbitrary but a hint that something meaningful should be picked.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it with text, use

```
alert($(this).text());
```

If you want the value, use:

```
alert($(this).attr('value'));
```

If you give the `div` a `data-value='a'` then you can use

```
alert($(this).data('value'));
```

Comment: so can i place data-value in other's elements as well?

Comment: Yes, you can give `data-value` to any element you want. Just make sure you call it by using `.data('value')` in `jQuery`. @BenWong

Answer (score 0):

use [text](http://api.jquery.com/text/) instead

```
alert($(this).text());
```

val() is only for input elements